# Google Chrome showing white 'borders' around images with 'background-repeat: repeat'

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-repeat

Google Chrome is suddenly showing a fine white border (not an actual border) around my images which have a background-repeat property. Must be because of a Chrome update, but I can't seem to get rid of it.

[image]
 I'm running version 55.0.2883.95 on a retina mac. Firefox, Safari, and Chrome Mobile all work fine.
You can see what I mean on [this site](http://wietsedevries.eu/).

**Update: Apparently it's because of the hdpi pixel density of my retina screen, so this seems like an issue for the Chrome dev team.**

Comment: Can you share a url? May have to use a hack for a min.

Comment: @yardpenalty the url is already there. Are you using a HDPI Mac?

Comment: Sorry I missed it. No I am not. What images?

Comment: *Wietse*, are _you_ using a HDPI Mac?

Comment: @Roy: yes, a retina display, that seems to be a factor. When I zoom out to 50%, the borders disappear.

Comment: Okay, I think that's it then. I don't see it on my Chrome version (same as you) on a Mac (non HDPI).

Comment: It used to look fine before though.

Comment: Me either. Btw very cool site! What technologies are you using on it?

Comment: Thanks:) just some css and js.

Comment: Just wanted to note that I too am experiencing this same bug in 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on a retina-display Macbook Pro. Reducing the zoom to 50% makes the rendering bug go away as noted.